# convert a memory location to string in Ghidra

Tags: ida, ghidra

I would like to have a decompiled pseudo-code in `Ghidra` like:

```
FUN_4c4363e8("Hello world");
```

This is what usually I see in `IDA` , but in Ghidra, by default I get such a code:

```
FUN_4c4363e8((char*)(DAT_4c447798));
```

Is there a way to force the decompiler to convert the `DAT_4c447798` memory address to `"Hello world"` null-terminated string?

**Edit** -> Please find [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/32484/45167) the solution to my question.